# Second Law of Thermodynamics and heat flow

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

So I'm confused with The Second Law of Thermodynamics.

It says that heat flows from the high temperature to low temperature. For example, if we put a glass of cold water on the dining room, the cold water will eventually have the same temperature as the dining room, because heat will flow from the air in the dining room into the cold water. The cold water "gains" heat and the air in the dining room "looses" heat. But, why does the temperature in the dining room remain the same? Shouldn't it become colder?

The same goes for a thermometer when someone that has a fever uses it. Will their body temperature loose heat because the heat will flow from their body to the thermometer?

Comment: Long before you study 2nd Law, way back in high school, you are supposed to learn that the heat Q needed to change only the temperature of an object is given by $Q=mc\Delta T$. The mass of a thermometer is way smaller than that of a human being; and the human being is continuously making heat from stored food anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> The cold water "gain" heat and the air in the dining room "loose"
> heat. But, why the temperature in the dining room remain the same?
> Should it be colder?

It is cooler. But the change is so small that it is essentially immeasurable. That's because the heat capacity of the room and its furnishings is so much greater than the glass of water. In thermodynamics we refer to this as a "thermal reservoir".

> The same goes for thermometer, if someone that has fever use
> thermometer. Will their body temperature loose heat because of the
> heat will flow from the body to the thermometer?

Yes their body will lose heat to the thermometer. But now there are two reasons why its temperature doesn't decrease (other than locally where it contacts the thermostat). One is, like the room, the body's heat capacity is much larger than the thermometer. Second, the body regulates its temperature by metabolic processes (chemical reactions in the body's cells that change food into energy) so that, unlike the room, it *generates* heat.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes to both, if heat is transferred from a large object to the small one, it changes the temperature of both large and small objects.

In the case of the room we consider that the room is so large that any change in temperature is compensated by the room being in contact with walls and other rooms. The environment is so large that we can neglect any change in the environment.

In the case of the person with fever is the same, only a tiny fraction of heat will go to the thermometer to change its measurement. But this fraction is so tiny that we can neglect any change in the patient temperature. If you have large amount of thermometers, you could in principle lower the temperature of the patient.

Comment: If we use the "system" and "surrounding" term, then

Comment: If we use the "system" and "surrounding" term, can we say that the "cold water" and "thermometer" is the system and the "dining room" and our "body" is the surrounding? If yes, then, is the temperature of the surrounding will always remain the same, because we could just neglect the heat flow because it is so small compared to the surrounding? @Mauricio

Comment: @aki that is right the temperature of the surrounding is considered to be held constant. Of course this has its limitation if the water container and thermometers are very large compared to the room/patient then you have to calculate the temperature difference to be sure.